# XML filtering of Event log using two conditions via AND

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue with filtering Windows event logs using an XML query.

What I am trying to do is have the XML query find event number 4688 in the security log created in the last 5 minutes and that part is working fine. 
I also need to exclude events that have the new process `name = C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` **and** `Subjectusername = HanSolo`.

My current filter is excluding all events with `NewProcessName = C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` regardless of SubjectUserName and excluding all events for `SubjectUserName = HanSolo`.  I need to exclude the combination of C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe and HanSolo in the same event.

```
$filterxml = @"

<QueryList>
   <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
     <Select Path="Security">*[System[(EventID=4688) and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) &lt;= 180000]]]

and

*[EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] !='C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' and 
            Data[@Name='SubjectUserName'] !='HanSolo']]

      </Select>
   </Query>
</QueryList>

"@

$event10 = Get-WinEvent -Filterxml $filterXml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the combination of two conditions is `a && b` its exclusion/inversion is `!(a && b)` which is expanded via inversion of each operand along with the logical operation: `!a || !b`, so here we go:

```
and
*[EventData[not(Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] = 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' and 
                Data[@Name='SubjectUserName'] ='HanSolo')]]
```

or

```
and
*[EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] !='C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' or 
            Data[@Name='SubjectUserName'] !='HanSolo']]
```

Comment: I was unable to get your solution to work, but thank you for the quick response and you have helped point me in the right direction.  It seems when you are trying to match a combination of conditions you have to use = not !=  However you have to wrap it in Supress Path tags between </Select> and </Query> like so

Comment: I also matched based on index number instead of @name=                                                 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------<Suppress Path="Security">*[EventData[Data[2]='HanSolo' and Data[6]='C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe']]</Suppress>